# how to silence annoying wsl terminal bell without turning off all windows system sounds

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Things I have tried:

- added `bind 'set bell-style none'` to the end of wsl `~/.bashrc`
- added `echo 'set bell-style none' >> /etc/inputrc` to the end of `/etc/inputrc`

after restarting and observing no change in the frequency of annoying 'up chimes' and 'down chimes' I finally went into [whatever they call the control panel now] and set Sound Scheme to "None".

Is there any other way to silence the wsl terminal (so easy in actual ubuntu) that doesn't involve this heavy-handed approach?

Comment: Go back to Control Panel, Sound, Sounds tab, and see the list of sounds. Test each one (I looked and did not see Terminal which I have here). When you find the sound, just turn that one off. Try this and see if if works for you.

Comment: When are you getting the bell? Are you sure this is emitted by bash, or is it by some application?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the you can now turn this off natively in the command shell options. Go to settings by clicking on the little down arrow near the tab add plus sign. Then click on the penguin in the left column. Then advanced. And then modify the bell notification style.

[image]